# Anti-matter black hole and time

Tags: black-holes, time, antimatter, popular-science

I have recently read some hard science-fiction story based on an assumption that if time stops (from external observer's perspective) on the event horizon of black hole, then in an anti-matter black hole's horizon the time would pass infinitely fast (same perspective)

I thought it was impossible, but I'm not sure anymore.

**What would be the effect of approaching the event horizon of an anti-matter black hole?**

Is it possible that an infinity of time passes in a finite time (from our point of view) ?

Fun follow-up: if so, can a result of infinite computation be returned to our timeline?

Comment: More on "anti-matter black holes": http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25982/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5615/2451

Answer (score 5):

A black hole may result from a gravitational collapse of either matter or antimatter, but the black hole itself is a geometrical object — a feature of the shape of space-time, not a material object. The behaviour of space-time at or near to a black hole is the same however it originates, so long as the bulk is electrically neutral; and a charged black behaves the same regardless of whether its charge is due to having absorbed e.g. more protons or more positrons.

Therefore, there is no real distinction between a "matter" black hole and an "antimatter" black hole; in particular, a black hole which happened to form due to the gravitational collapse of a large amount of antimatter would be indistinguishable from a black hole arising from a collapse of matter (or indeed from a sufficiently dense combination of matter and antimatter, arising from a dense nugget of matter and a dense nugget of antimatter brought together that only achieve the  "critical density" as they approach each other).

Comment: "The behaviour of space-time at or near to a black hole is the same however it originates." This is false. For example, a black hole with electrical charge differs from an electrically neutral black hole.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this for me Niel. 
@BenCrowell Could You elaborate (or better - give a link)?

Comment: @BenCrowell: right, a bit too hastily written. Edited.

Comment: @naugtur: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem