# What happens if you dump antimatter into a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, antimatter

Let's say you have a 10 solar mass BH and dump 10 solar masses of antimatter into the BH... What would happen?

Would I have a 20 solar mass BH?
Would the BH explode 
Do we even understand what would happen to antimatter in the BH?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25982/

Answer (score 14):

We have experimental evidence that antiparticles have positive inertial mass. We have no experimental evidence regarding the gravitational mass of antiparticles, because we can’t find or create enough antimatter to measure its gravity. However, I believe most physicists would be *extremely* surprised if antimatter had antigravity, as there is no reason why it should, and it would violate the equivalence principle. So the answer is almost certainly that you would simply have a 20 solar mass black hole.

Comment: If antimatter had "negative gravity", how would it gravitationally interact with normal matter? I'm sure we can tell for example that antimatter falls towards the earth.

Comment: @aquirdturtle Can we tell that (empirically)? While it's certainly true, the amount of antimatter we can generate is so small that the effect of gravity on them would be negligible. It's not like we can put it in a vacuum and see if it falls.

Comment: @forest Of course we can! We can even trap and detect antimatter atoms in vacuum for minutes at a time in magnetic traps. https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2025. I haven't combed through the literature of these experiments enough to see if they've literally dropped the antimatter or if anyone specifically reported that "antimatter falls", but it seems likely that this has been tested.

Comment: @aquirdturtle It's not a very easy experiment and we are [still working on it](https://home.cern/news/news/experiments/new-antimatter-gravity-experiments-begin-cern). A [previous experiment in 2013](http://alpha.web.cern.ch/node/248) only gave a very loose constraint.

Comment: @Graipher If that result is ever wittled down to an interval not containing 1g downwards accelration, at least we will have disproven the equivalence principles that general relativity builds on. It's impressive that they manage to measure it at all, and I'm sure the methods are grounbdbreaking. The result itself, however, seems, to me as an amateur, somewhat useless because of the comedically sized error bars.

Comment: @aquirdturtle Yes, demonstrating that antimatter falls down is hard. What's even harder is demonstrating that a lump of antimatter produces gravity just like regular matter does. We expect both of those things to be true, but it may be a *very* long time before we can build a large enough lump of antimatter to test the latter claim.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for the links. I'm somewhat startled if it's really true that even the sign of the gravitational force is experimentally in question. It's very easy to see the effects of gravity on matter in normal atomic physics experiments, indeed in my lab we can even see the effect of gravity on single atoms.

Comment: @Graipher Why doesn't this experiment work: Get any antimatter source and aperture it down to a narrow, if weak, horizontal beam of antimatter. Set up two very coarse antimatter detectors far down the beam line vertically displaced above and below the horizontal, and measure counts in each. When properly calibrated this should tell you whether the antimatter is falling up or down. Of course I'm not saying this is "easy", but it seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @aquirdturtle Because getting anti-matter is hard. Producing anti-protons is not very hard, but when you produce them they move very fast and soon hit something they annihilate with. We can trap them, but ideally you want to perform a gravitic falling experiment with a neutral particle, to rule out stray electromagnetic fields messing with your result. Getting anti-hydrogen is very hard, since you need to slow down the anti-protons far enough that they can actually form atoms, with positrons. Both of which will anihilate as soon as they hit any other atom. (Cont'd)

Comment: @aquirdturtle (cont'd) Then you need to trap the atoms, which means cooling them further down to capture it. And only then you can start your measurements. In the case of the preliminary measurement they had 434 anti-hydrogen atoms to work with. Since they have a non-zero temperature the still have a kinetic energy, which means they don't just fall down. Also the trap takes some time to shut off. The paper of the preliminary measurements has all the details: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3644108/

Answer (score 6):

> Let's say you have a 10 solar mass BH and dump 10 solar masses of antimatter into the BH... What would happen?

This depends, like most things in relativity, on where the observer is.

First note that it makes no difference whether it's energy or matter (just a form of energy) inside the event horizon - it will stay inside the event horizon from the point of view of an observer outside the horizon.

As far as we know antimatter is, for the purposes of gravitation, the same as matter.  There is no "anti-gravity" effect if you're thinking that.  So the anti-matter and matter "attract" each other (although that's not quite how general relativity describes it formally).

Also, although we talk about mass resulting in the gravitational field, it's more accurate to say that *any* form of energy contributes to the gravitational field.  So it's really a case of how much energy is inside the event horizon that defines it's size.  Adding more mass or converting mass to energy makes no difference in this sense.  More energy of any form increases the size of the event horizon (with some details in the case of charged particles and extra angular momentum).

So from the observer outside all that happens is that the event horizon gets bigger by the equivalent effect of 10 solar masses.

If you are an observer traveling with the antimatter, then you see the antimatter pass across the event horizon and continue falling into the black hole.  If it encounters matter it will annihilate some of the antimatter.  However once past the event horizon the energy or particles from that annihilation will not leave the black hole.  It will in principle fall to the singularity at which point it doesn't matter what form of energy it is.

> Would I have a 20 solar mass BH ?

Yes-ish.

In practical terms that much mass-energy dumped into a black hole quickly would certainly result in the release of gravitational waves that would "use up" up some of that energy, possibly a substantial part of that mass-energy.

> Would the BH explode ?

No.

You can't break these things as far as we know.

> Do we even understand what would happen to antimatter in the BH?

Whatever could happen it outside, could happen inside.  The energy equivalent will remain inside and someone on the outside can never know what happened it - that's essentially what an event horizon is : events on one side are not knowable by someone on the other side.

Comment: So the antimatter does not annihilate any of the singularity?

Comment: In practical terms we don't actually know if a singularity exists.  The model (GR) that predicts singularities is describing a rather abstract "ideal" and does not include any quantum effects (and we have no complete theory describing the universe under such extreme conditions as "near singularity" ).  Some form of annihilation is possible, but the energy-mass will *still* be inside the event horizon, which is all that matters as far as the existence of the black hole (event horizon) is concerned.

Comment: "You can't break these things as far as we know". Yes, you can, you just need to wait long enough for Hawking radiation to cause the black hole to evaporate.

Comment: @nick012000 I think that qualifies as normal wear and tear (or possibly what is nowadays called "planned obsolescence"), not a break. :-)

Comment: @Rick In standard GR, a singularity isn't an object made of stuff. [Ben Crowell says](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144458/123208) "A singularity in GR is like a piece that has been cut out of the manifold. It's not a point or point-set at all". A quantum gravity theory may give us a different model of what happens at the core of a BH, but even so, there's simply not enough room there for normal fermionic matter (or antimatter). Classical GR is very likely correct down to the size of a proton or smaller, and you can't fit 10 solar masses of fermions into a region smaller than a proton!

Comment: When black holes collide, the energy released as gravitational waves comes from their mutual gravitational potential energy. Crudely speaking, the BHs don't lose any of their internal mass. However, when considering a region that contains 2 BHs saying exactly where the mass lives isn't straight-forward. ;)

Comment: @PM 2Ring: when two planetoids fall towards one another, gravitational potential energy is converted into kinetic energy. When they collide and coalesce, this kinetic energy is usually dissipated. You're then left with a [mass deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation). The mass of the new object is less than the mass of the two original objects. This is because gravitational potential energy is mass energy. Do ask around and check that I'm right about this, or ask a question about it. Note though that IMHO this creates issues for colliding black holes.

Comment: @StephenG - Here is a dumb question...  If Hawking radiation causes the mass of a BH to decrease due to the antimatter particle being sucked into the event horizon, why does larger amounts of antimatter being sucked in not cause the singularity to shrink even faster?

Comment: @Rick *"If Hawking radiation causes the mass of a BH to decrease due to the antimatter particle being sucked into the event horizon"* It doesn't. BTW, Hawking radiation is primarily photons, and photons are their own antiparticle. But anyway, if a black hole had regular matter in it & you dropped in some antimatter, the mass of the hole would increase. If that antimatter annihilates with existing matter, sure, the rest mass of both would be converted to light, but the mass of the BH wouldn't change.

Comment: @JohnDuffield "*mass deficit* [...] *ask a question about it*" - I have asked a question that then in the comment thread narrowed down to the mass deficit. Please see the last comment by Void after his answer here confirming that you are correct: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356029/energy-of-falling-into-a-black-hole

Answer (score 2):

As the others have answered, our present theories say that you would end up with a double sized black hole.

One way of looking at it is the following:

Suppose the original matter still exists in the singularity. It probably doesn't, but just *suppose* that it does.

And you drop anti-matter on it and it annihilates. What happens during annihilation isn't that the matter and anti-matter just disappears, instead both gets converted into radiation.

And now the important point: That radiation cannot escape the singularity!  It is still stuck. It still has the same mass as the matter and anti-matter it was created from.

From outside the black hole it will be impossible to know if the singularity consists of matter, anti-matter or radiation, the total mass is all that counts.

(This thought experiment is probably invalid in that the singularity *doesn't* remember what it was made from)